# Replace element in array by checking condition in another list

Tags: matrix, replacement, list-manipulation

Im trying to escape doing double loops given the large number of items in the arrays.

I have two list with a format like this:

```
list1={{1,2,0},{1,3,0},{4,6,0},{2,3,0}} (*Third element of each item is 0*)

list2={{3,2,1},{1,3,1},{4,5,1}} (*Third element of each item is 1*)
```

List might not be of equal length.

If the first two elements of a list match I want to replace that item in `list1` with the corresponding item in `list2`.

```
result={{1,2,0},{1,3,1},{4,6,0},{2,3,0}}
```

Since there seems to be confusion I'll provide another example:

```
test1={{0.5,0.5,0},{1,1,0},{1.5,1.5,0},{2.0,2.0,0}};
test2={{0.5,0.5,1},{2.0,2.0,1}};
```

The results should then be:

```
 result={{0.5,0.5,1},{1,1,0},{1.5,1.5,0},{2.0,2.0,1}};
```

Which includes every item in `test1`.

I am sorry if its confusing, this is my first post here.

I have this setup but it takes too much time:

```
densitydata = Reap[Do[If[{cross[[m, 1]],cross[[m, 2]]} == {fullzone0[[n,1]] = fullzone0[[n, 2]]},
Sow[cross[[m]]], Sow[fullzone0[n]]],
{n, 1,Dimensions[fullzone0][[1]]}, {m, 1,Dimensions[cross][[1]]}]][[2]][[1]];
```

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one.

Comment: Thanks for taking the [Tour]! Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part tomorrow.  As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: What should be returned for the lists {{1, 2, 0}} and {{3,2,1}, {1, 2, 1}}?

Comment: @CarlWoll It should return every element in list1 with the elements that meet the criteria replaced. so it should be.  result={{1,2,0},{1,3,1},{4,6,0},{2,3,0}

Comment: In addition, what should be returned for the lists {{1, 2, 0}, {3, 2, 0}} and {{3, 2, 1}?

Comment: I'm giving examples of `list1` and `list2` different from yours, and wondering what the expected output is. Specifically, are you comparing the first element of `list1` with only the first element of `list2`, or with all elements of `list2`?

Comment: @CarlWoll Oh, right. So if the lists are  {{1, 2, 0}} and {{3,2,1}, {1, 2, 1}} then the output should be {{3,2,1}, {1, 2, 1}}. However, for my arrays, all elements present in list2 are in list1. However if for some reason this happens the output most always include any item with the third element equal to one.

Comment: I expected {{1, 2, 0}} to become {{1, 2, 1}}, not {{3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}. Why did the length of list1 increase? Also, your example has a list2 where not elements in list2 are in list1.

Comment: The end goal is to have a list with all possible points {x,y,1} that are in list2,list1 just marks all possibles x & y points. Hence why list1 is of the form {x,y,0}. If for some reason there is an x,y combination not present in list1 it should be added.

Comment: Giovanni, (1) **_If the first two elements of a list match I want to replace that item in list1 with the corresponding item in list2_** AND (2) **_If for some reason there is an x,y combination not present in list1 it should be added_**.  You can't have both, no?

Comment: @GiovanniBaez i am lost now. Your question mentions something else and now you are mentioning that all elements absent in the first list should be added to it? is it even possible?

Comment: The final result should be every element in list1, the one with third element 0, with the special cases, the ones appearing in list2, replaced. In my arrays the cases prompted by @CarlWolll will never show up.

Comment: @AliHashmi I edited the question with another example, to try and show what Im searching for. Sorry if I confused you guys.

Comment: @GiovanniBaez please see Carl's or my answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update after discussions in comments**

*I've revised my code to use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace) with a level spec, and to create rules only from list2, since the latter list can be much smaller than the first list. This provides a speed boost of about 50%.*

```
update[l1_,l2_] := Module[{p, q, r=l1},
    p = Replace[
        l1[[All,;;2]],
        Dispatch @ Thread @ Rule[l2[[All,;;2]], l2[[All,3]]],
        {1}
    ];
    q = Replace[p[[All,0]], {List->0,_->1}, {1}];
    r[[Pick[Range[Length[l1]], q, 1], 3]] = Pick[p,q,1];
    r
]
```

For your initial example:

```
update[list1, list2]
```

> {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}}

For your latest example:

```
test1={{0.5,0.5,0},{1,1,0},{1.5,1.5,0},{2.0,2.0,0}};
test2={{0.5,0.5,1},{2.0,2.0,1}};

update2[test1,test2]
```

> {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2., 2., 1}}

**Timing**

Since you mention working with large arrays, here's the speed of `update` on some made up data:

```
list1=Sort@RandomReal[1,{10^4,3}];
list2=RandomSample[list1,10^3];
list2[[All,3]]=RandomReal[1,10^3];

update[list1,list2];//AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.01681, Null}

```
list1=Sort@RandomReal[1,{10^6,3}];
list2=RandomSample[list1,10^5];
list2[[All,3]]=RandomReal[1,10^5];

update[list1,list2];//AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.99171, Null}

**Old code**

```
update2[l1_,l2_] := Module[{r=l1, l=Join[l2,l1]},
    r[[All,3]] = r[[All, ;;2]] /. Dispatch@Thread@Rule[l[[All, ;;2]],l[[All,3]]];
    r
]
```

Comment: +1 for the performance !

Comment: Your code now beats mine handily in performance.  Nice. +1

Answer (score 10):

```
list1 = {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 0}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}};
list2 = {{3, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 1}, {4, 3, 1}};

If[Most[#] === Most[#2], #2, #] & @@@ Transpose[{list1, list2}]
```

> `{{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}}`

Answer (score 9):

```
f[v1_, v2_] := If[Most[v1] == Most[v2], v2, v1];
MapThread[f, {list1, list2}]
```

which gives you `{{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}}`

Revised to incorporate your unequal length list condition

```
Map[(match = Cases[list2, Join[Most[#], {_}]]; 
     If[match == {}, #, match[[1]]]) &, list1]
```

Comment: I may have oversimplified the format, the lists are not equal length. So it makes it more tricky.

Answer (score 8):

```
mask = Boole[# == {0, 0}] & /@ Unitize[list1[[;; , ;; 2]] - list2[[;; , ;; 2]]];

list1 mask + (1 - mask) list2
```

> {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}}

**Update:** For lists with possibly unequal lengths:

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1 = Module[{ml = Min[Length /@ {##}], mask, l1 = #, l2 = #2}, 
    mask = Boole[# == {0, 0}] & /@ Unitize[l1[[;; ml, ;; 2]] - l2[[;; ml, ;; 2]]];
    l1[[;; ml, -1]] = l1[[;; ml, -1]] mask + (1 - mask) l2[[;; ml, -1]]; l1] &;
```

Examples:

```
list1 = {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 0}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}} ;
list2 = {{3, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 1}, {4, 3, 1}};
f1[list1, list2]
```

> {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}}

```
SeedRandom[1]
list3 = {#, #2, 2} & @@@ RandomInteger[5, {3, 3}];

f1[Join[list1, list3], list2]
```

> {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}, {4, 2, 2}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 2}}

```
f1[list1, Join[list2, list3]]
```

> {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}}

```
test1 = {{0.5, 0.5, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2.0, 2.0, 0}};
test2 = {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {2.0, 2.0, 1}};
f1[test1, test2]
```

> {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2., 2., 0}}

Comment: The first approach is really nice, I never thought of just using matrix algebra for list manipulation like this.

Comment: `f1[{{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 0}}, {{1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}]` produces a strange result. I would expect either `{{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 0}}` or `{{1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}}`, but not `{{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}}`.

Comment: Thank you @Carl. Fixed it now. I had `list1` and `list2` leftover from previous versions changed them to `l1` and `l2`.

Comment: @kglr This method seems to be the one better suited for very large arrays. If the numbers in the list are not integers would it present a problem in the execution of the code?

Comment: @kglr The following test cases produce a negative value for the third element in the result. test1= {{0., 0.045105, 0.}, {0., 0.047361, 0.}, {0., 0.049616, 
  0.}, {0.998047, 1.67229, 0.}},test2={{0.208984, 0.120657, 1}, {0.765625, 1.59448, 1}} give  {{0., 0.045105, -1.}, {0., 0.047361, -1.}, {0., 0.049616, 
  0.}, {0.998047, 1.67229, 0.}}

Comment: Am I crazy or are `list1` and `list2` hard-coded in `f1`?

Comment: Mr.Wizard, yes they were  -- before my edit 2 hours ago:)

Answer (score 8):

The question was changed after I wrote my first method making it invalid.

For the new question I propose simply using Associations.

```
test1 = {{0.5, 0.5, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2.0, 2.0, 0}};
test2 = {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {2.0, 2.0, 1}};

fn2 =
  KeyValueMap[Append] @*
      (AssociationThread[#[[All, ;; -2]] -> #[[All, -1]]] &) @* Join;

fn2[test1, test2]
```

> ```
> {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2., 2., 1}}
> ```

This is faster than the presently Accepted answer:

```
list1 = Sort@RandomReal[1, {10^6, 3}];
list2 = RandomSample[list1, 10^5];
list2[[All, 3]] = RandomReal[1, 10^5];

r1 = update2[list1, list2]; // AbsoluteTiming
r2 = fn2[list1, list2];     // AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> ```
> {3.30789, Null}
>
> {2.30772, Null}
>
> True
> ```

---

#### *Method for original question:*

```
pos[a_, b_][p_, i_] :=
 p[[
   "AdjacencyLists" //
     SparseArray[Unitize[Subtract @@ {a, b}[[All, p, i]]], Automatic, 1]
  ]]

fn[a_, b_] :=
  Module[{x = a, pp},
    pp = Fold[pos[a, b], Range@Length@b, {1, 2}];
    x[[pp]] = b[[pp]];
    x
  ]

fn[list1, list2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}}
> ```

If I have time I'll benchmark this and other answers later unless someone else undertakes that first.

Comment: +1 for awesome speed :) your speed beats @Carl by a slight margin :)

Comment: @AliHashmi Thanks!  I just updated my answer to include a single timing point; I get a fairly large improvement with this case on my system.

Answer (score 7):

**Assuming:** *"for my arrays, all elements present in list2 are in list1"*

The code:

```
GatherBy[Join[list1, list2], Most][[All, -1]]
```

works if either `DuplicateFreeQ[Drop[list1, None, -1]]` is `True` or if it is `False` you want duplicates of list1 to be deleted.

Answer (score 6):

```
list1 = {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 0}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}, {3, 2, 0}};
list2 = {{3, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 1}};

replace[list1_, list2_] := 
Module[{temp, pos, val, l = list1}, 
temp = Outer[If[SameQ @@ Map[Most]@{##}, Last[#2]] &, list1, list2, 1];
val = Cases[temp, _?NumericQ, {2}];
pos = Map[First]@Position[temp, _?NumericQ, {2}];
l[[pos, -1]] = val;
l]

replace[list1,list2]

(* {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}, {3, 2, 1}} *)
```

one more case:

```
test1 = {{0.5, 0.5, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2.0, 2.0, 0}};
test2 = {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {2.0, 2.0, 1}};

replace[test1, test2]
(* {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2., 2., 1}} *)
```

Comment: Your method modifiers `list1` (or `test1`). That means something like `replace[{{1, 2, 0}}, {{1, 2, 2}}]` won't work. Also, it always updates the result to 1.

Comment: @CarlWoll now it does not modify list1 in place. Also now it does not update to 1 always. But your performance is much much superior to this answer

Answer (score 5):

Another one-liner:

```
list1[[All, ;; 2]] /. (Join[list2, list1] /. {x_, y_, z_} :>  ({x, y} -> {x, y, z}))
```

> {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}}

For the OP second example:

```
test1[[All, ;; 2]] /. (Join[test2, test1] /. {x_, y_, z_} :>  ({x, y} -> {x, y, z}))
```

> {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2., 2., 1}}

(With [ReplaceAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html.en), the first rule that matches is applied to each part)

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 1} /. {1 -> 10, 1 -> 100}
```

> {10, 2, 3, 4, 10}

**Edit**

If the third element of `list1` is always 0 and the third element of `list2` is always 1 the following, I think, should also work:

```
(list1 /. (list2 /. {x_, y_, 1} :>  ({x, y, 0} -> {x, y, 1})))
```

and

```
(test1 /. (test2 /. {x_, y_, 1} :>  ({x, y, 0} -> {x, y, 1})))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list1 = {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 0}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}};
list2 = {{3, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 1}, {4, 3, 1}};

f[{{x__, _}, a : {x__, _}}] := a
f[{a_, _}] := a

f /@ Transpose[{list1, list2}]
```

> {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}}

Answer (score 1):

```
test1 = {{0.5, 0.5, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2.0, 2.0, 0}};
test2 = {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {2.0, 2.0, 1}};

KeyValueMap[Append] @ Map[Last] @ GroupBy[Most -> Last] @ Join[test1, test2]
```

{{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2., 2., 1}}

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];

list1 = {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 0}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}};
list2 = {{3, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 1}};
r1 = {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}};

test1 = {{0.5, 0.5, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2.0, 2.0, 0}};
test2 = {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {2.0, 2.0, 1}};
r2 = {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2.0, 2.0, 1}};

f[our_List, repl_List] := Module[{lut = (Most@# -> #) & /@ repl},
  Sequence @@@ Lookup[lut, {Most@#}, #] & /@ our
  ]

f[list1, list2] == r1
f[test1, test2] == r2
```

> True
>
> True

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use `GroupBy` to construct a rule:

```
l1 = {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 0}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}};
l2 = {{3, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 5, 1}};
r1 = {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 3, 1}, {4, 6, 0}, {2, 3, 0}};

rule = Values@GroupBy[Catenate@{l1, l2}, Most, 
       If[Length@# > 1, Position[l1, #[[1]]] -> #[[2]], Nothing] &];
```

Finally, using `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[l1, rule] === r1

(*True*)
```

An alternative to construct the above rule using `GatherBy` and `Dispatch`:

```
l1 = {{0.5, 0.5, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2.0, 2.0, 0}};
l2 = {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {2.0, 2.0, 1}};
r2 = {{0.5, 0.5, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1.5, 1.5, 0}, {2.0, 2.0, 1}};

rule = Dispatch@(Position[l1, #1] -> #2 & @@@ 
       Select[GatherBy[Catenate@{l1, l2}, Most], Length@# > 1 &]);
```

Testing with `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[l1, rule] === r2

(*True*)
```