# Listing what has been deleted by DeleteDuplicatesBy

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I list the items deleted from `DeleteDuplicatesBy`?

For example:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[{{a, b}, {f, c}, {d, b}, {e, c}, {a, c}}, Part[#, 2] &]
```

gives

> `{{a, b}, {f, c}}`

However, is there any simple way to get the list `{{d, b}, {e, c}, {a, c}}` of deleted pairs?

Comment: At least closely related: [How to get list of duplicates when using DeleteDuplicates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37936/5478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Coolwater's fine [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151298/45431) to [Replace element in array by checking condition in another list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/151293/45431) you can use [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy):

```
Catenate @ GatherBy[
    {{a,b},{f,c},{d,b},{e,c},{a,c}},
    Last
][[All, 2;;]]
```

> {{d, b}, {e, c}, {a, c}}

*update*

Here's another very similar version:

```
Catenate @ GroupBy[
    {{a,b},{f,c},{d,b},{e,c},{a,c}},
    Last,
    Rest
]
```

> {{d, b}, {e, c}, {a, c}}

Comment: Thanks a lot! This would be very useful to me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way.

```
data = {{a, b}, {f, c}, {d, b}, {e, c}, {a, c}};
p1 = DeleteDuplicatesBy[data, Part[#, 2] &]
```

> `{{a, b}, {f, c}}`

```
p2 = DeleteCases[data, Alternatives @@ p1]
```

> `{{d, b}, {e, c}, {a, c}}`

Here is another.

```
p2 = Complement[data, p1]
```

Comment: Note that both of these solutions fail for data with two identical items. I assume that the goal is to get a list `p2` s.t. `Sort[p1~Join~p2]==Sort[data]`

Comment: @Mathe172 I am aware of the your 1st assertion, but it not clear to me the 2nd applies.

Comment: @m_goldberg Although there is some problem for two identical items, it is still workable in my case as there is no identical items in my data set.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{a, b}, {f, c}, {d, b}, {e, c}, {a, c}};
```

Since V 13.1 we have `DeleteElements`

```
DeleteElements[list, DeleteDuplicatesBy[Last] @ list]
```

{{d, b}, {e, c}, {a, c}}

`DeleteElements` preserves the ordering, but gets very slow with long lists

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{a, b}, {f, c}, {d, b}, {e, c}, {a, c}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit`:

```
Catenate@Rest@SequenceSplit[list, s : {a_, b_ ..} :> s]

(*{{d, b}, {e, c}, {a, c}}*)
```